# How to access own API in native application using Google OAuth 2.0 for authentication?

Tags: php, android, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have an app that uses the OAuth2 Google sign-in system and we want to store data from the users that sign in into our app on our back-end during the initial registration.

This is the way we got it set up:

1. Users signs in with the app using Google sign-in
2. We get an ID Token and send this to the server
3. On the server we verify this token is valid using Google library and save the info we get back from the verification

**We also need the user to be able to update/insert data into the back-end when he's authenticated.**

After the initial registration, how do we do this?

Do we send the ID Token from client to server each time they call the API on our back-end? In this case how to handle expired tokens?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to make your API a first-class citizen in your system and have it require access tokens that are specifically issued to it** instead of accepting Google authentication related tokens that were issued to your client application then **you need to have an authorization server that specifically issues tokens for your API**.

This authorization server can still delegate user authentication to Google, but then after verifying the user identity it will issue API specific access tokens that better satisfy your requirements, like for example, including specific scopes then used by your API to perform authorization decisions.

For a more complete description of this scenario you can check Auth0 [Mobile + API architecture scenario](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/application/mobile-api).

> In this scenario you have a mobile application ("Client") which talks to an API ("Resource Server"). The application will use OpenID Connect with the Authorization Code Grant using Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) to authenticate users.

The information is Auth0 specific and you can indeed use Auth0 as an authorization server for your own API while still maintaining Google authentication support, however, most of the theory would also apply to any OAuth 2.0 compliant provider.

**Disclosure**: I'm an Auth0 engineer.